# Java Api for bugzilla to get details about the bug

Tags: java, bugzilla

I am new to JAVA API. Can anyone help me with integrating bugzilla to my web application using JAVA API? For example when the user enters the bugid, I need to fetch the details about bug as description from bugzilla. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use j2bugzilla (http://code.google.com/p/j2bugzilla/). It's an active project and probably it can fulfill your needs.

Following your needs, you can call `GetBug` method that does the retrieval of the bug (Java) object, and after that you can call `getDescription` method to get description of it.

Comment: As the author of the library, I just released a new version, so inactive is a bit strong ;)

Comment: I changed my answer, glad to see there's a new version. I'm an user too.

Comment: @giampalo j2bugzilla try connecting bugzilla by xmlrpc.cgi. is there a way to connect bugzilla using jsonrpc.cgi? check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21326249/2334391) which we tried using xmlrpc.cgi gives error

Comment: Post a question, you have better chances to solve your problem. Thousands of programmer here around ;)